# regex match exact pattern within string

Tags: python, regex

if I have the following string 'some numbers 66666666666666666667867866 and serial 151283917503423 and 8888888' and I want to find 15 digit numbers (so only 151283917503423) how do I make it so that it doesn't match the bigger number and also deal with the possibility that the string can just be '151283917503423' therefore I cannot identify it by it possibly containing spaces on both sides?

```
serial = re.compile('[0-9]{15}')
serial.findall('some numbers 66666666666666666667867866 and serial 151283917503423 and 8888888')
```

this returns both 66666666666666666667867866 and 151283917503423 but I only want the latter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [word boundaries](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
serial = re.compile(r'\b[0-9]{15}\b')
```

> \b Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a
>   word. A word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric or underscore
>   characters, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a
>   non-alphanumeric, non-underscore character. Note that formally, \b is
>   defined as the boundary between a \w and a \W character (or vice
>   versa), or between \w and the beginning/end of the string, so the
>   precise set of characters deemed to be alphanumeric depends on the
>   values of the UNICODE and LOCALE flags. For example, r'\bfoo\b'
>   matches 'foo', 'foo.', '(foo)', 'bar foo baz' but not 'foobar' or
>   'foo3'. Inside a character range, \b represents the backspace
>   character, for compatibility with Python’s string literals.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use word boundaries to ensure you don't match unwanted text on either side of your match:

```
>>> serial = re.compile(r'\b\d{15}\b')
>>> serial.findall('some numbers 66666666666666666667867866 and serial 151283917503423 and 8888888')
['151283917503423']
```

Answer (score 2):

Include word boundaries. Let `s` be your string. You can use

```
 >>> re.findall(r'\b\d{15}\b' ,s)
 ['151283917503423']
```

where \b asserts a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)

Answer (score 1):

Since word boundaries `\b` contain 2 assertions each, I would use a single assertion
instead.

`(?<![0-9])[0-9]{15}(?![0-9])`

should be quicker?